# Как проверить, является ли текст палиндромом?

Tags: python

Проверить, является ли текст палиндромом, игнорировать знаки пунктуации, пробелы и регистр букв. Например, `А роза упала на лапу Азора` - это палиндром.

```
def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]

def is_palindrome(text):
    return text == reverse(text)

something = input('Введите текст: ')
if(is_palindrome(something)):
    print('да, это палиндром')
```

Как сделать так называемую `"проверку дальше"`, то есть, если что-то не так, то `break`, в противном случае `"проверяем дальше"`.

Мне не нужно решение всей задачи, а только можете эту часть объяснить.

Comment: А что вы хотели сначала проверить и куда впихнуть break? У вас используется цикл?

Comment: @gil9red, я думал в кортеж засунуть все знаки и пробел. и сделать перебор с помощью цикла, и если мой текст равен какому-то элементу кортежа тогда `"проверять дольше"` и пропускать их. Вот как сделать именно вот эту `"проверку дальше"`

Comment: Добавил пример через составление строки с удалением игнорируемых символов

Answer (score 1):

Пример проверки через регулярку:

```
import re

def is_palindrome(text: str) -> bool:
    # Приводим к единому регистру
    text = text.lower()

    # Удаляем все символы кроме 0-9, а-я, a-z
    text = re.sub('[^\dа-яёa-z]', '', text)

    # Пустая строка не палиндром
    if not text:
        return False

    return text == text[::-1]


text = 'А роза упала на лапу Азора'
print(is_palindrome(text))  # True
```

Пример через проверку символа вхождением в группу символов:

```
import string
IGNORE_SYMBOLS = string.whitespace + string.punctuation


def is_palindrome(text: str) -> bool:
    # Приводим к единому регистру
    text = text.lower()

    # Оставляем символы, что не входят в IGNORE_SYMBOLS
    text = ''.join(c for c in text if c not in IGNORE_SYMBOLS)

    # Пустая строка не палиндром
    if not text:
        return False

    return text == text[::-1]
```

---

Пример использования в цикле:

```
while True:
    text = input('Введите текст: ')

    # Ввели пустую строку
    if not text:
        break

    if is_palindrome(text):
        print('да, это палиндром')
    else:
        print('Нет, это не палиндром')
```